# jquery color picker hover element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help with Hover class.

As you can see the code then I have to hover the elements, but unfortunately they do not change color. have any ideas how to make everything working?

I have followed the code:

```
$('#color_mix_menu_top').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#menu > ul > li:hover > a, #menu > ul > li > a:hover, #menu > ul > li > div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        $('#color_mix_menu_top').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
}
});
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, i.e. where `hsb`, `hex` and `rgb`are defined and the accompanying html it is hard to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

have you logged or debugged to verify your jquery selector is working?  e.g

```
console.log("" + $('#menu > ul > li:hover > a, #menu > ul > li > a:hover, #menu > ul > li > div').length)
```

just to be sure you aren't missing something there.

Comment: normal selector everything works, but with "#menu > ul > li:hover" does not work.

Comment: have you tried setting the css value from the debugger to figure out if that's going wrong?  e.g in firebug, or in the chrome console:

Comment: another problem is that I have a # menu> ul> li: hover> a table with Other selector.

Answer (score 0):

alright then a simple solution:

```
$('#menu > ul > li > a, #menu > ul > li > div').data('bg', '#' + hex);
```

then

```
$('#menu > ul > li > a').hover(function(){
     $(this).css('background', $(this).data('bg'));
}, function(){
     void(0);
})
```

and if you want to reset color on mouseout:

```
var currBG;
$('#menu > ul > li > a').hover(function(){
    currBG = $(this).css('background');
    $(this).css('background', $(this).data('bg'));
}, function(){
    $(this).css('background', currBG);
})
```

You can adjust it a bit according to your need

Comment: but i need hover elements also!

Comment: another problem is that I have a #menu> ul> li: hover > a table with #menu > ul > li > div selector. when i select color for #menu > ul > li > div and #menu> ul> li aselector in css #menu> ul> li: hover > a not work as properly.

Comment: I don't think `li:hover` is a valid jQuery selector, you have to find a way around it.